# unresolved external symbol _forceCRTManifestCUR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unresolved-external, lnk2001

When I am trying to build one of my `C++` solution for `x64` architecture. I am getting alot of these errors:

```
Error   34  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _forceCRTManifestCUR
```

- Project was working fine before but I had to reinstall windows and so
  VS since than it is having this problem.
- It builds all fine when i build it for `x32`
- My Operating System is `Windows XP - X32` (Visual Studio - 2008) can this be the reason? I
  hope it is possible to build a solution for `x64` architecture while
  on a `x32` system?

Please guide me how can i resolve this issue.

Thankyou.

Comment: `_forceCRTManifestCUR`? .. No.

Comment: Hard to believe that's the only linker error you get, you normally get a raft of other ones when you mix up code that's compiled with /MT with code that's compiled with /MD.  Did you just pick one of them and ignored the others?

Comment: There are total `52` errors. First `51` says the above mentioned error and last one `52th` says: `fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`